# the usage of "the most of it"

Tags: american-english, phrase-usage

please help to confirm the subject usage:

make your expertise the most of it.

I am going to use this slogan in my ppt.

I want to express the meaning of that we help everyone to deploy and practice their own talent in the most large field, the highest level.
I need it in mother tongue English express. 
Thank you

Comment: What is ppt? Powerpoint? Pulsed Plasma Thruster? Precision Pressure Transducer?  Presidential Prayer Team?

Comment: Yes. PPT=Powerpoint. I want to prepare a presentation on our new staff training course

Answer (score 1):

*Make the most of something* means, according to Cambridge Dictionary:

> "to use or enjoy something as much as possible"[1](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/make-the-most-of-something)

In your case you might want to rephrase it as:

> make the most of *your expertise*.

That way, *your expertise* is the object, rather than *it*, which is kind of vague. So by putting it like this you emphasise *your expertise*, which is probably what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank you JJJ, Can we correct this express as : " make the most of your expertise ?"

Comment: @JamesCox that is what you want to say, right?  _To use your expertise as much as possible_, or did you want to say something else?

Comment: My means is: The God gives you a talent that other people doesn't have. So this is your unique value in this society. You should deploy it as much as possible to get benefit from value for you and others around you.  As I use Chinese. So I hope get English good people help me correct use English to express this meaning in very nature like English. Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: ["You just have to play with the cards that you're dealt"-- Michael Scott](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D7y5_AsZGT0). Maybe that's something? The cards represent different talents and everyone has been given a different set of cards (talents).

Comment: you meant that the slogan should be as : < You just have to play with the cards that you are dealt > Is it?

Comment: @James Cox The slogan can be phrased differently, this is how it's used in an episode of The Office (television series).

Comment: have you any good suggest for this meaning?